# Repeat Microsoft Power Automate step in switch case

Tags: azure-devops, automation, switch-statement, power-automate

I have a flow that creates Azure DevOps (ADO) work item based on a Microsoft Form. Depending on the choice they select, a different ADO work item is made or a combination of work items are made. Here's a screenshot of what I have so far:

[image: Power Automate Flow]

As you can see on the far right, the third choice is a combination of the same ADO work items for the first two choices (*complete and consumer data collection has ended.* **and** *launching in the near future.*).

I had to clone over those same work item steps. So if I make a change to the "Create a work item to Set up GTM", I have to make sure the "Create a work item to Set up GTM (copy)" is the same to stay consistent. To save me from making duplicates, is there a way to set a "variable" of the ADO work items where I can edit it once and have it repeat later on in my steps?

Comment: @Ethan the "variable" is actually an Azure DevOps step. When I looked at what you are referring to, I don't think I see what you're referring to

Comment: You are using Power Automate, so you can pass variables to those Azure DevOps steps.

Comment: @Ethan Well, I'm not trying to pass variables into the ADO step, rather the ADO step is the "variable". I want some of them to repeat to the Switch that I shared a screenshot above. This way, I don't have to manually copy the same one over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Power Automate doesn't have the ability to repeat a certain step or function, the workaround is to use the **Control Condition**. This essentially acts as an IF/THEN statement based on the values. Here's what it looks like now:

[image: Power Automate Flow]

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps “Create a new work item” flow has 5 parameters; Org Name, Proj Name, Work Item Type, Title, Description. Let’s say if you want the “Create a new work item (copy)” to have the same Proj Name as the first one. You would create a string variable and call it ProjName, and then pass that string into both the copy and original “Create a new work item.” That way, whenever you change the string, it will change both.

[image]

Comment: I see what you mean, that could work as well. I ended up using the Control Condition instead so I don't have to define all of the parameters and simplify my steps. Thanks.